# Cannot load CoqIDE plugin for vim

Tags: vim, coq, coqide

I'm trying to use the CoqIDE for vim plugin I found on [this page.](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4388)

I put the coq_IDE.vim file in ~/.vim/ftplugin folder. My current .vimrc file is:

```
set showcmd
set number
imap hl <Esc>
filetype plugin on
```

But when I start vim CoqIDE doesn't load automatically (I see no change whatsoever compared to normal vim, so I don't think it did). And when I try to load it manually by the command `:source coq_IDE.vim`, I get the following error message:

```
E484: Can't open file coq_IDE.vim
```

What could be the source of this error?

Here are some additional information that might be relevant:

1) I am running Ubuntu 14.04.

2) I checked that `:version` in vim shows `+perl`.

2) I am running vim from terminal, not gvim.

3) I tried removing and reinstalling different versions of vim (vim, vim-gtk, vim-gnome)

4) The CoqIDE installation guide says that `coqtop.opt` should be accessible via the `PATH` variable. Since I'm not even sure what this means, this might be the problem here, but that seems unlikely. From what I understand vim is getting errors when trying to read `coq_IDE.vim`, so it's not even getting to the part where it's looking for `coqtop.opt`.

5) I have CoqIDE installed from Ubuntu Software Center.

6) With `:echo &runtimepath` I get: `~/.vim,/var/lib/vim/addons,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles,/usr/share/vim/vim74,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/after,/var/lib/vim/addons/after,~/.vim/after`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instructions are bad.

Put the file in `~/.vim/plugin` not `~/.vim/ftplugin`

The file layout should look exactly like the file layout found in this mirror for the plugin. https://github.com/vim-scripts/CoqIDE. (Maybe take a look at [pathogen](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2332) or [vundle](https://github.com/gmarik/Vundle.vim),).

The reason the `:source coq_IDE.vim` fails is vim is looking for the file `coq_IDE.vim` in the current directory and it isn't there. Use the full path to file if you are going to source it manually. (You shouldn't need to though.)

Comment: I changed the folder name so that `coq_IDE.vim` is now in `~/.vim/plugin`, but still getting the same errors. Perhaps I should also downgrade the plugin version to 0.96b to match it more exactly? (I'm using 0.97.b right now.) I'm new to vim and I haven't used vundle yet, but I guess I'll check that out as well.

Comment: @user3287108 which error are you talking about? And downgrading shouldn't make a difference. Does the output of `:scriptnames` show the file being loaded?

Comment: Wait, I changed directory into `~/.vim/plugin` before using the `:source coq_IDE.vim` command and it doesn't give any more errors, so I think it's working. Now I'm getting errors with `coqtop` part but I guess that's a different question. Thanks.

Comment: @user3287108 do not manually source it. The plugin is automatically sourced at startup when it is in the ~/.vim/plugin folder